# Finding duplicate string logical expressions

Tags: java, parsing, tree, binary-tree

I have a string logical expression like below

```
String1 - (category = ((A || B) && C)) && (location = 1 && (2 || 3))
String2 - (category = (C && A)) && (location = 1 && 2)
```

I need to block user from entering similar conditions, in above case both conditions are similar as at runtime for given values they might evaluate to same output.

Can I convert the expressions to binary expression tree and sort the nodes alphabetically and finally check if one tree is a subtree of another ?

Would that be a feasible solution ? Or is there any library already available for handling such scenarios ?

Comment: you mean something like `SELECT 1 FROM Expressions WHERE expression = 'YOUR_STRING'` ?

Comment: No, user will upload the conditions and I need to evaluate those conditions against database stored conditions. Assuming if I convert those conditions to binary tree expression and store that expression in database, can I use dB capabilities to check stored expression against incoming expression ? What approach must be followed in such situations ? Is drools the only way ?

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to keep the most common expression. Each expression which is subsumed by another should not be placed in the database? I think the best approach would be to transform it to a normal form. It should be possible to decided whether one normal form subsumes another.

Comment: The data is unstructured. Keys are not known in advance, user will provide this data through file upload (CSV). I will be reading the file in chunks, need to do row comparison and also check dB(mongo) if such condition already exists.